# I am getting applitool error while opening cypress

Tags: cypress

The plugins file is missing or invalid.
Your pluginsFile is set to C:\Users\cypressautomation\cypress\plugins\index.js, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The pluginsFile must be a .js, .ts, or .coffee file.
Or you might have renamed the extension of your pluginsFile. If that's the case, restart the test runner.
Please fix this, or set pluginsFile to false if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.
Error: Cannot find module '@applitools/eyes-cypress'

```
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Documents\cypressautomation\cypress\plugins\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\6.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\6.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:15)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:27)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\\cypressautomation\cypress\plugins\index.js:24:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1173:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at runPlugins (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\6.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:177:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\6.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\index.js:8:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:30)
```